How to efficiently chunk/embed json? (ollama, chromadb, gp4allembeddings/langchain)
I've been working on a simple chatbot, it responds to inquiries in intercom and in telegram. It makes a database of information to pull from based on current support articles in Intercom. It worked pretty well with 150 articles, but as I've added more and its up to almost 400 it seems to completely miss easy questions now, and I feel like i'm not ingesting all that information in the most efficient way possible.
It uses Ollama/Llama3 for the model, i have a custom modelfile that looks like:

FROM llama3
PARAMETER temperature 0.3
SYSTEM You are a helpful AI assistant for the "X" platform. Your role is to provide detailed, accurate answers to user questions based on the information in your knowledge base, with the goal of assisting users without requiring a human response when possible. If a question can have multiple answers depending on the situation, provide guidance on the different options. When giving instructions, be as specific as possible. Never answer questions that are remotely off-topic. Just let them know you can’t help with that.

It uses gpt4allembeddings/langchain for embedding and chromadb for the database.
I have a pre-prompt implemented that reads like:

Answer the question based on the provided context. Do not include introductory phrases. If the question is unclear or unrelated to the context, simply state "I apologize, I can't help with your query, let me get a team member to assist." Do not provide additional explanations.

The json that intercom is providing looks like this:
    [
      {
        "id": "123",
        "type": "article",
        "workspace_id": "123",
        "parent_id": null,
        "parent_type": null,
        "parent_ids": [],
        "title": "Title",
        "description": "Description",
        "body": "Body",
        "author_id": 123,
        "state": "draft",
        "created_at": 171,
        "updated_at": 171,
        "url": null
      },
      {
        "id": "234",
        "type": "article",
        "workspace_id": "234",
        "parent_id": null,
        "parent_type": null,
        "parent_ids": [],
        "title": "Title",
        "description": "Description",
        "body": "Body",
        "author_id": 123,
        "state": "draft",
        "created_at": 171,
        "updated_at": 171,
        "url": null
      },

Here is my script please dont judge i'm an absolute hobbyist and this is my first time trying to dive into AI stuff:
`
import json
import logging
import os
import aiohttp
import asyncio
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from quart import Quart, jsonify, request
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
from telethon.errors import RPCError, ChatAdminRequiredError, ChannelPrivateError
from telethon.tl.types import PeerChannel
from langchain_community.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain_community.embeddings import GPT4AllEmbeddings
from langchain_core.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain_community.llms import Ollama
from langchain.callbacks.manager import CallbackManager
from langchain.callbacks.streaming_stdout import StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
from langchain.docstore.document import Document
from hypercorn.config import Config
from hypercorn.asyncio import serve
import time

os.makedirs('logs', exist_ok=True)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s', handlers=[
    logging.FileHandler("logs/app.log"),
    logging.StreamHandler()
])

start_time = time.time()

# .env
load_dotenv()
api_id = os.getenv('API_ID')
api_hash = os.getenv('API_HASH')
bot_token = os.getenv('BOT_TOKEN')
intercom_token = os.getenv('INTERCOM_TOKEN')
chat_id = int(os.getenv('CHAT_ID'))
qa_chain_prompt_template = os.getenv('QA_CHAIN_PROMPT_TEMPLATE')

app = Quart(__name__)

client = TelegramClient('logs/tg_chat', api_id, api_hash)

vectorstore = None
qa_chain = None

QA_CHAIN_PROMPT = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["context", "question"],
    template=qa_chain_prompt_template,
)

llm = Ollama(model="llama3-temp03", callback_manager=CallbackManager([StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()]))

async def fetch_all_pages():
    url = 'https://api.intercom.io/articles'
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {intercom_token}',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
    all_documents = []
    all_data = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        while url:
            async with session.get(url, headers=headers) as response:
                if response.status != 200:
                    logging.error(f"Failed to fetch data: {response.status}")
                    break
                data = await response.json()
                all_data.extend(data.get('data', []))
                if 'data' in data and data['data']:
                    documents = [Document(page_content=article["body"]) for article in data["data"] if article["body"].strip()]
                    all_documents.extend(documents)
                url = data.get('pages', {}).get('next', None)
    with open('info.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(all_data, f, indent=2)
    logging.info(f"Total records received: {len(all_data)}")
    return all_documents

async def rebuild_vectorstore():
    global documents, vectorstore, qa_chain
    try:
        documents = await fetch_all_pages()
        if documents:
            vectorstore = Chroma.from_documents(documents=documents, embedding=GPT4AllEmbeddings())
            logging.info("Documents processed and vector store rebuilt.")
            qa_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
                llm,
                retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever(),
                chain_type_kwargs={"prompt": QA_CHAIN_PROMPT},
            )
        else:
            logging.error("No valid documents with non-empty body found.")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error rebuilding vector store: {str(e)}")

async def handle_query(query):
    if qa_chain is None:
        logging.error("QA chain is not initialized.")
        return {"response": "Initialization error: Vector store not available. Check log for details.", "time_taken": 0}

    start_time = time.time()
    try:
        result = qa_chain.invoke(query)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error during query handling: {str(e)}")
        return {"response": "An error occurred while processing the query.", "time_taken": 0}

    end_time = time.time()
    time_taken = end_time - start_time

    logging.info(f"Query result: {result}")

    if isinstance(result, dict):
        result = result.get('result', "No result field found in response.")
    elif isinstance(result, str):
        result = result.strip()
    else:
        result = str(result).strip()

    if not result:
        result = "I apologize, but I don't have enough information to provide a helpful answer."

    return {"response": result, "time_taken": time_taken}

@app.route('/intercom', methods=['POST'])
async def intercom_handler():
    data = await request.get_json()
    query = data.get("body")
    if query:
        result = await handle_query(query)
        response = result["response"]
        time_taken = result["time_taken"]
        return jsonify({"response": response, "time_taken": time_taken}), 200
    else:
        logging.error("No query provided in the request")
        return jsonify({"error": "No query provided"}), 400

@app.route('/rebuild_vectorstore', methods=['POST'])
async def rebuild_vectorstore_handler():
    await rebuild_vectorstore()
    return jsonify({"message": "Vector store rebuilt"}), 200

@client.on(events.NewMessage(pattern=r'^\.x (.+)', func=lambda e: e.text.lower().startswith('.x ')))
async def answer_query(event):
    query = event.pattern_match.group(1)
    logging.info(f"Received query: {query}")
    result = await handle_query(query)
    response = result["response"]
    time_taken = result["time_taken"]
    await event.respond(f"```{response}```\n**Time to generate: {time_taken:.2f} seconds**", parse_mode='Markdown')

@client.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='/rebuild'))
async def rebuild_vectorstore_command(event):
    logging.info("Received /rebuild command. Rebuilding the vector store...")
    await event.respond("Rebuilding database...")
    await rebuild_vectorstore()
    await event.respond("Database rebuilt.")

async def run_server():
    global start_time
    config = Config()
    config.bind = ["0.0.0.0:5001"]

    async def custom_serve():
        end_time = time.time()
        time_to_boot = end_time - start_time
        await send_message(chat_id, f'<span style="color:red">Bot Online, Time to boot: {time_to_boot:.2f} seconds</span>')
        await serve(app, config)

    await custom_serve()

async def send_message(chat_id, message):
    try:
        entity = await client.get_entity(PeerChannel(chat_id))
        await client.send_message(entity, message, parse_mode='html')
    except ChatAdminRequiredError:
        logging.error(f"Failed to send message to {chat_id}: Bot lacks admin rights.")
    except ChannelPrivateError:
        logging.error(f"Failed to send message to {chat_id}: Channel is private.")
    except RPCError as e:
        logging.error(f"Failed to send message to {chat_id}: {str(e)}")

async def start():
    try:
        await client.start(bot_token=bot_token)
        logging.info("Telegram client connected.")
        await rebuild_vectorstore()
        await run_server()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error occurred: {str(e)}. Retrying in 5 seconds...")
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await start()

async def main():
    try:
        await start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        logging.info("Script interrupted by user.")
        await send_message(chat_id, '<span style="color:red">Shutting Down</span>')
    finally:
        logging.info("Shutting down...")
        await client.disconnect()
        logging.info("Client disconnected.")
        pending = [task for task in asyncio.all_tasks() if not task.done() and task is not asyncio.current_task()]
        for task in pending:
            task.cancel()
        await asyncio.gather(*pending, return_exceptions=True)
        loop.stop()
        loop.close()
        logging.info("Script stopped.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(main())
    except RuntimeError as e:
        logging.error(f"Runtime error: {str(e)}")
    finally:
        if not loop.is_closed():
            loop.close()`

I'm not sure if i am embedding the json correctly, i thought it would be straightforward in json format but the bad outputs make me second guess whatever im doing, really open to whatever, would love to learn what im missing here
